# ISAPI_Rewrite In IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I've been using ISAPI_Rewrite from Helicon (http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) on a Server 2003 box for years and have always had good luck with it.

I'm migrating all the sites on the 2003 box to a new shiny Server 2008 box.  I would prefer to not purchase a new license and I have heard that IIS 7 will have capability built in.

All the rewrites are setup in a .htaccess configuration file just like mod_rewrite for Apache.

Does anyone know if this capability ever got baked into IIS 7 and if so do you know of any good articles that explain how to get it all enabled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS7 does have the functionality built in, as you mentioned. You can either use a custom HttpModule, as described in [Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx).

Alternatively, you could install the the [IIS7 Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1691) as [described here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCAndTheNewIIS7RewriteModule.aspx).

Comment: No, it didn't exactly get built-in, you still have to download the modules, as you sort of linked to (still have to search/page through to find). Be accurate in what you post.  Because you have good links, I didn't vote this down, but don't mislead people by saying something is "built-in" when it isn't capable out-of-the-box or by simply modifying some installation parameters. It only gets "built-in" once ARR is installed, with all of its dependencies, including the separate urlRewrite module: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/erezs_iis_blog/2013/11/27/installing-arr-manually-without-webpi/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out the [IIS 7 URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't built-in until you install the Application Request Router (ARR) IIS Extension, and all of its dependencies, which you have to do in a specific order:

1. Web Farm Framework module.
2. External cache module.
3. URL Rewrite module.

Then the ARR module.

Each requires a separate download from [download.microsoft.com](http://download.microsoft.com), but all are free.

Reference:  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/erezs_iis_blog/2013/11/27/installing-arr-manually-without-webpi/